# How do I find the mean of a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use one function to find the mean of a list in Haskell. This is what I put in:
`let listmean x = (foldl (+) 0x)/(length x)`
And I get this:

> <`interactive>:43:18: error:
> • Could not deduce (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
> from the context: Foldable t
> bound by the inferred type of
> listmean :: Foldable t => t Int -> Int
> at :43:5-42
> • In the expression: (foldl (+) 0 x) / (length x)
> In an equation for ‘listmean’:
> listmean x = (foldl (+) 0 x) / (length x)

I've tried to use the built-in div function but no luck there either. I run Haskell on https://replit.com, could it be the website?

Comment: How did you use `div`? Works for me like this: ```(\x -> (sum x) `div` (length x)) [1..3]```

Comment: You can't use `/` on integers. You could convert everything to double as in `fromIntegral (...) / fromIntegral (...) :: Double`. If you want `div` instead you need to use backticks ``(...) `div` (...)`` or use it in prefix form `div (...) (...)`.

Comment: Interesting that `f 0x` is actually allowed (both `0` and `x` are parsed as individual arguments to `f`). But **please** never write it this way! _Especially_ not if the variable is called `x`. It's confusing both with general parsing rules, and hexadecimal literals in particular.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Now I want to go write a solution to something on codegolf.stackexchange.com that uses that.

Answer (score 0):

`/` takes two `Fractional`s (try `:info (/)` in ghci). So you need to convert the `Int` into, say, `Double`:

```py
main = print $ mean [0,1,1,2,3,5,8] -- 2.857142857142857

mean :: [Int] -> Double
mean xs = fromIntegral (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)
```